# How to create a trusted self signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https

I create a self signed certificate in IIS7.5 and I am getting an error that follows

```
    There is a problem with this website's security certificate. 


 The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.

Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.  
  We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.  
  Click here to close this webpage.  
  Continue to this website (not recommended).  
     More information 


If you arrived at this page by clicking a link, check the website address in the address bar to be sure that it is the address you were expecting. 
When going to a website with an address such as https://example.com, try adding the 'www' to the address, https://www.example.com. 
If you choose to ignore this error and continue, do not enter private information into the website. 

For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Browsers only trust certificates issued by some CA (Certificate Authority)'s only. You can generate a certificate for your own use but it will give you a warning saying "This certificate is not trusted". You can buy cheap SSL certificate from GlobeSSL.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Its not an error its a warning, the certificate you generated is not trusted by the browser.

To supress this on *machines you control* you can add the certificate to the trusted root CA store ([Example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)).

If this machine is on the internet/accessed by machines you do not control, you cannot alter this behaviour unless you purchase a cert from a trusted issuing CA.

Comment: If I do this process in my server can my clients access to that https without warning?

Comment: No, it must be done on each client machine & I would never ask a client to do that. You an pick-up a rapidssl cert for < $10

Comment: I have created a proxy server application. for all client machine connecting to this proxy application, I need to provide SSL certificate for ALL websites. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @AdityaBokade I don't know, better to ask a new question

Comment: That example you linked to shows how to fix a similar but different problem.  The error message here is that the certificate is issued for a different address, not an untrusted source, as mentioned by @spender in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Only **you** can trust a self signed certificate. If you want one that is universally trusted, you'll need to buy one from an issuing authority. However, it appears that this particualr certificate was issued for a different domain from the one that is being visited. FIx this, and you'll probably get another warning about trust.

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform this manually if you have the certificate file. Use the Windows management console tool - certmgr.msc. Among other features, it allows you to manually import self-signed certificates.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/view-or-manage-your-certificates

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the “Internet Explorer” icon, 
then choose “Run as administrator“ 
or just the application in “Internet Explorer”.

Visit the website, and choose the option to “Continue to this website (not recommended).”.

Click where it says “Certificate error” in the address bar, then choose “View certificates“.

Select “Install Certificate…“.

Select “Next“.
Select the “Place all certificates in the following store” option.
Select “Browse…“.

Choose “Trusted Root Certification Authorities“, then select “OK“.

Select “Yes” when prompted with the security warning.

Select “OK” on the “The import was successful” message
Select “OK” on the “Certificate” box.

Rerun the Applications.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

When you create a self signed certificate you must Trust the Certificate Authority with every device accessing the server. Nevertheless, that means that you must create also a root CA, and use it to sign the other certificates.
To be honest the process is a bit complicated and it already has given many people headaches before you.

## Solution

### Manually

You can either do it yourself, in which case I would advise you [this cheatsheet](https://github.com/ChristianLempa/cheat-sheets/blob/main/misc/ssl-certs.md#ssl-certificates-cheat-sheet) which is pretty well explained. But it's missing one step that seems pretty important to me: creation of the `fullchain.pem`. Where you basically need to concatenate all certificates into one file (CA and Certificate). I always had issues when that was not done.

### Half-automated

I ended up creating a script that does most of the painful part for you. It is pretty easy to use, and should include every step you need.

1. Download [Home-Certificate-Generator](https://github.com/Vinalti/Home-Certificate-Generator)
2. Execute `bash generate_certificate.sh` (see documentation or `-h` for more options)
3. Follow the instruction to create the Root CA and the certificates
4. Import the Root CA to your device (check the `-h` or this [cheatsheet](https://github.com/ChristianLempa/cheat-sheets/blob/main/misc/ssl-certs.md#install-the-ca-cert-as-a-trusted-root-ca))
5. Import the Certificates on your servers (that you should look in the documentation of whatever your server is)

You can also use an existing Root CA.
The documentation is in the [GitHub page](https://github.com/Vinalti/Home-Certificate-Generator) of the project.

Feel free to help me improve the project.